# GitHub: how to remove a file from git history (especially that of the GitHub repository)?

Tags: file, github, repository, history

I have a GitHub repository which contains some big files which I want to permanently remove from its history. I have cloned

GitHub has a nice page which can be used to remove such big files (https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data). So, I cloned my GitHub repository, carefully followed the instructions from that page, and sure enough the size of my local repository is now much smaller.

So, from there, I thought I would next force push everything back to my GitHub repository using:

```
git push --force --all
```

I checked the SHA-1 values of my GitHub repository against those of my local clone and they all match. From there, I thought I would clone my 'new' GitHub repository and check its size, thinking it would be the same as that of my original clone, but... it's!

After some investigation, the (closed) pull requests in my GitHub repository reference some of those big files I deleted. So, those files are still around. (For all I know, there may be other things in GitHub which still refer some/all of my big files.)

So, **what do I need to do to get my GitHub repository as small as my local repository?** (Assuming it can at all be done!)

I mean, the whole idea for wanting to 'clean up' my GitHub repository is that people who want/need to clone it would end up with a small clone while right now it's still relatively big.

FWIW, to create a new GitHub repository, push my 'clean' repository to it will indeed result in a new 'small' (GitHub) repository, but... it won't have all the issues, comments, pull requests, forks, etc. of my current GitHub repository, hence it's not an option for me. If anything, I would be happy to lose the pull requests (and, possibly, anything else that refers some/all of my big files), but the question is whether it can actually be done?...

FWIW #2, I am aware of a Python script to transfer issues from one GitHub repository to another (https://github.com/mkorenkov/tools/blob/master/gh-issues-import/gh-issues-import.py), but it didn't work for me (some issues were missing, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It can be very hard to clean up a git repository because even when you delete files git still stores them. There are likely better ways to do it but you may want to just make a new repo from scratch. Don't bother including files that will never change like videos or pictures and don't include your binary files. Just remember that taking files out of a git repo doesn't delete their data.

Comment: Well, to delete files from a git repository certainly deletes their data. This is definitely what happened to my local git repository. I am just not able to get the files to be deleted from GitHub.

About creating a new GitHub repository: this exactly what I don't want to do since I would lose a hell of a lot of GitHub specific information (e.g. issues) which I don't want.

Comment: Actually it doesn't, you just can't see it anymore, that is how you can still revert back versions in git, basically the point of version control

Comment: First paragraph  https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data you may want to read more of it, may solve your issue

Comment: aaronman, either I didn't make myself clear or you didn't get my question. In other words, I didn't use git rm to remove the files, but git filter-branch so that the files get removed from the repository's history, and this is exactly what happened to my local repository. So, there is no way I can ever get those files back (and this is the whole point of https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data).

Comment: I don't know, but somehow I would be surprised if one could.